# I have a practice project i did that i need to compare two Lists . How do i make the comparison?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CompareNumbers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 4, 7, 12, 0, 15 });
        List<int> newValues = new List<int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Compare();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Compare()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!newValues.Contains(myValues[i]))
                {
                    newValues.Add(myValues[i]);
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < newValues.Count; x++)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a List with some numbers. And a List that is empty.

I need to create a comparison of the two Lists and check for new numbers.

First time the List newValues is empty so the condition should make that it will add all the numbers from myValues. So now newValues contain all the numbers.

Now i need to make some conditions first for one number then for two numbers then for three numbers.

I mean that if a new number I have a new number added to the myValues list to check if this number exists in myValues if it does don't add it to newValues if it's not add it.

Then if two numbers added to the myValues list and then if three numbers added. To check if the numbers already exist in myValues if they do, don't add them to newValues, if they don't exist yet in myValues, then add them to newValues.

My problem is how to make all the conditions in the inner loop ? There should be number of IF's .

Also this part I did I'm not sure if it's right:

```
if (!newValues.Contains(myValues[i]))
{
   newValues.Add(myValues[i]);
}
```

I didn't explain it good enough the logic.

I have this empty List:

```
List<NewsLine> OnlyNew = new List<NewsLine>();
```

Then I have this class:

```
class NewsLine
{
   public string text;
   public string time;
   public string link;
}
```

Then this method:

```
private void AddOnlyNew(List<NewsLine> test_lnl)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < test_lnl.Count; x++)
    {
       for (int y = 0; y < OnlyNew.Count; y++)
       {
       }
    }
}
```

Now I need to check each time if there is a new text,time,link then add them.

It's not enough to check only the text or time or link I should make in the inner loop some check's using IF to decide if to add them to the OnlyNew List.

EDIT

```
class NewsLine
   {
      public string text;
      public string original_time;
      public string link;

      // Straight compare of the two objects.
      public static int Compare(NewsLine n1, NewsLine n2)
      {
         // How to do the comparisdon is up to you.
         // In this example, if the first property is different we use that, 
         // else if the second property is different use that, else use the final property.
         if (n1.text != n2.text)
            return string.Compare(n1.text, n2.text);
         else if (n1.original_time != n2.original_time)
            return string.Compare(n1.original_time, n2.original_time);
         else
            return string.Compare(n1.link, n2.link);
      }
```

Comment: Added more code to my question to explain the logic more. It's not only to compare it's more to check for new numbers/items and to decide if to add them or not to the new List.

Comment: Since you changed what you are looking for it changes the answers already posted but i'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want to do from your updated post.

Comment: Why do you need a `Form` for that?

Comment: The answer by Tsukasa should resolve your issue.

Comment: Updated my question for the last time i know it's wrong but this answer i got is what i mean but i still don't understand how it work so i did a project with the numbers but the last part i added is what i mean.

Comment: @user3852926 My answer will do what you are asking in 1 line without all the extra code you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do this.
This will add any items from existingValue that don't already exist in newValues.

```
newValues.AddRange(existingValue.Except(newValues));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a nit test, use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` if they need to be the same order, `CollectionAssert.AreEquivilent()` is they only need to contain the same items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop on the first list to make sure all the items are added:

```
foreach(int existingValue in myValues)
{
    if(!newValues.Contains(existingValue))
    {
        newValues.Add(existingValue);
    }
}
```

This can also be done using LINQ:

```
newValues.AddRange(myValues.Where(n => !newValues.Contains(n)));
```